# Transfer a string from one ASP.NET MVC project to a different project (two different solutions) hosted on same IIS WebServer

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-config

Looking for advice or a solution on this problem.

I have 2 projects. If you click on Project A's URL, it should redirect you to Project B (which is a login form), and then once you successfully enter your username and password, should direct you back to Project A again to continue.

The first step is completed - I get to the login form (Project B) fine, but once logged in successfully, I want to send the username back to Project A to say Welcome, User in the View - and this is what I cannot get right.

I tried `Session` - that did not seem to work. This is what I have tried in the `web.config`:

```
<!--
<sessionState mode="StateServer"
              stateConnectionString="tcpip=loopback:42424"
              cookieless="false"
              timeout="20"/>
-->
```

Also instead of the loopback, I also tried using the server's name, but got the same result.

On IIS, I setup the server state mode on the application as well, but same result - it gets a null value in Project A's Session.

I have also tried using headers, but this also returns a null value to Project's A getheader.

Is there an example that I am missing? I did a lot of research on this, but it's not working for me. There has to be a way to post information to another application.

Answer (score 0):

The way these problems are usually solved is at the HTTP level.

Even if you 'know' that both projects are going to be hosted on the same machine, this may not be the case in eternity. Perhaps in the future, they may be hosted on different machines, or on a server farm.

Perhaps, in the future, a programmer decides to rewrite one of the systems in a different programming language, or use a different hosting environment.

You'll be better off treating separate web sites/services as truly separate.

Usually, login actions will embed a `returnUrl` as a URL parameter when they redirect browsers to a login site; something like this:

```
https://example.com/login?returnUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fexample.org%2Ffoo%2Fbar%3Fbaz%3D0%26qux%3Dquux
```

Notice here that I've URL-encoded the `returnUrl`. The login system can then URL-decode it and redirect the browser back to the origin once login is done.

Try to use your browser's developer tools (F12) to see how some existing login systems work.

Comment: thanks for your comment, but this will only be a temporary solution because we are changing domains, and while this is going on I don't want to make use of the Windows authentication because it causes issues. So what you are saying is that I copy and paste my Account Controllers and Views to all the 20+ apps that need the authentication?